# Started work on a time based business game- one similar already exists... What should i do?

Tags: adventure-games

Yeah so like i said, i started to work on a time based game that involves business investments, and as it turns out, there is a game called adventure capitalist that has pretty much the same idea about it. I planned to greenlight my game on steam and i found that adventure capitalist is on steam. Im not sure what i should do. Should i continue but make changes to the game (and if so, what sort of changes) or should i give up and work on something else. I should have mentioned this earlier but in the game, you make investments in the electronic industry, and each type of investment will have a different payout per second and a different base investment price to other types. For example, investing in computers will cost you £500 and have a payout of £5/second but investing in smartphones will cost only £100 and have a payout of £1/second. When you can afford it, you can level up your investment. I havent really added any more to the game than that so any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's your game, your time, your life, do what you want :) Make a decision and run with it.

Comment: No matter how original you think your concept is, people are going to compare it to other games anyway. Don't worry about it. If you've got the passion for it, keep working on it! I guarantee that if you're not deliberately trying to copy adventure capitalist, you'll end up with something more or less original anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Game mechanics are not [patentable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patentability), [trademarkable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark), or [copyrightable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright). Hence if your game is distinct in implementation, branding, and naming, you should be OK from a legal perspective.

From a marketing perspective though, the existing game has some [first-mover advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_mover_advantage), unless you can [differentiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_differentiation).  Can you deliver a game so much better than the competitor's that you can steal their whole market?  If so, go for it.  If not, it might be easier to look for a less occupied niche.